# collectionView loading xib instead of content from array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view which should display an array of items from an object loaded from firebase. However, when the app first loads up it just displays the xib without the content loaded (sometimes the content has loaded and other times it hasnt). Only when I add a new item to the array and reload the collection view does the content load into the view. This is what the app looks like when it first opens. The collection view just shows the xib [image: collection view not loaded] however, after adding a new item, the collection view looks as it should [image: collection view as it should look] My question is, how would I make sure that the collection view is always loaded before showing the unloaded xib? Thank you.

methods:

```
var currentUser: User!
var listCategories: [String] = ["Friends Lists", "Friends", "People"]
var lists = [Media]()

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return listCategories.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {

        return lists.count

    }else{
        return 0
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.listCell, for: indexPath) as! ListCell

    cell.currentUser = currentUser
    cell.media = lists[indexPath.item]
    cell.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor.black, alpha: 0.08, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 10, spread: 0)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

    return cell

}

//section header view
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    let sectionHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.sectionHeader, for: indexPath) as! SectionHeaderView
    let category = listCategories[indexPath.section]
    sectionHeaderView.sectionTitle = category
    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

The next method which is called in `viewWillAppear`

```
func fetchMedia() {
    Media.observeNewMedia { (media) in
        if !self.lists.contains(media) {
            self.lists.insert(media, at: 0)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Inside Media class

```
class func observeNewMedia(_ completion: @escaping (Media) -> Void)
{

    WADatabaseReference.media.reference().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let media = Media(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
        completion(media)
    }

}
```

inside collectionViewCell

```
import UIKit
```

import Foundation
import SAMCache

```
class ListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var nameButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var listTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var boughtLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var boughtProgress: UIProgressView!

var numOfItems = 0
var numOfBought = 0
var counter: Double = 0{
    didSet{

        boughtProgress.isHidden = false
        let fractionalProgress = Float(counter)
        boughtProgress.setProgress(fractionalProgress, animated: true)

    }
}
var currentUser: User!
var media: Media! {
    didSet{
        if currentUser != nil{
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
}

var cache = SAMCache.shared()

func updateUI(){

    let profileImageKey = "\(media.createdBy.uid)-profileImage"
    if let image = cache?.object(forKey: profileImageKey) as? UIImage {

        self.profileImageView.image = image

    }else{
        media.createdBy.downloadProfilePicture { [weak self] (image, error) in
            if let image = image {

                self?.profileImageView.image = image
                self?.cache?.setObject(image, forKey: profileImageKey)

            }else if error != nil {

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }


    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    mainView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //profile image

    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2.0
    profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //name

    nameButton.setTitle("\(media.createdBy.firstName) \(media.createdBy.lastName)", for: [])
    nameView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    nameView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //date

    dateLabel.text = "\(convertDateFormatter(theDate: media.dueAt))"
    dateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.3)
    dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    dateLabel.layer.cornerRadius = dateLabel.bounds.height / 2.0
    dateLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //title

    listTitle.text = "\(media.title)"

    //progress

    numOfItems = media.items.count
    print("num of items \(media.items.count)")
    counter = Double(numOfBought)/Double(numOfItems)
    boughtLabel.text = "\(numOfBought)/\(numOfItems) Bought"
    boughtProgress.layer.cornerRadius = boughtProgress.bounds.height / 2.0
    boughtProgress.layer.masksToBounds = true

}

@IBAction func arrowDidTap(){

    print("arrow tapped")

}

func convertDateFormatter(theDate: String) -> String
{
    print(theDate)
    let newFormat = DateFormatter()
    newFormat.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let dueDate = newFormat.date(from: theDate)
    newFormat.dateFormat = "dd MMM yy"
    print(newFormat.string(from: dueDate!))
    return  newFormat.string(from: dueDate!)

}

func getColourFromTag(tag: String) -> [CGColor] {

    if tag == "Christmas" {

        return [Colours.gradients.festive.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.festive.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Birthday" {

        return [Colours.gradients.lime.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.lime.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Valentines Day" {

        return [Colours.gradients.strawberry.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.strawberry.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Charity" {

        return [Colours.gradients.blueberry.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.blueberry.end.cgColor]

    }else if tag == "Event" {

        return [Colours.gradients.fire.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.fire.end.cgColor]

    }else{
        return [Colours.gradients.midnight.start.cgColor, Colours.gradients.midnight.end.cgColor]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Without an appropriate part of the code you're using it is very hard to answer. Please, share some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

At least now it seems to me like you doesn't reload your collectionView with empty data and it just load what is inside the .xib file.
Try to `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` or something when your array is still empty to avoid this.

Comment: sorry I should have explained that I am already doing this in viewDidLoad

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` what's the `count` of your `listCategories` and `lists` properties?

Comment: lists.count = 0
listCategories.count = 3